# Microsoft.Identity.Client AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf doesn't get token from cache

Tags: .net-6.0, azure-ad-msal, bearer-token, microsoft.identity.web, on-behalf-of

I have a problem to figure out how implement cache with AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf. Every time when I call code below for the same user I get different token, so I suppose that there is no inner cache mechanism or something like that.

```
    var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
        .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
        .WithAuthority(authority)
        .Build();

    var result = await app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }, userAssertion)
                          .ExecuteAsync()
                          .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I tried to add `app.AddInMemoryTokenCache();` from Microsoft.Identity.Web and it works but then one request can last even 21 seconds and this is not an option.

Is anyone who faced problem like that?

Edit:
I found some solution. I added to ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder two lines and now it take tokens from cache:

```
.WithLegacyCacheCompatibility(false)
.WithCacheOptions(CacheOptions.EnableSharedCacheOptions)
```